# ProductProjectionByKeyGet not retrieving Channel Reference by Key

Tags: commercetools

When getting product details by product key from commercetools, The response that I get does not have the **Channel Key** as `channelId` but instead I get a **random UUID** *(I believe the reference id)*.

```java
final ProductProjectionByKeyGet productProjectionByKeyGet =
                ProductProjectionByKeyGet.of(productKey, ProductProjectionType.CURRENT)
                        .withExpansionPaths(product -> product.allVariants()
                                .attributes().valueSet());
        return clientManager.getClientForProjectKey(ctAdapterProperties, projectKey)
                .execute(productProjectionByKeyGet).toCompletableFuture().get();
```

In the response after getting product details, If we take a look into the property `prices[].channel.id` the value for it is a UUID but inside the commercetools, I have the channel key as a string like: `<store>-<online>`

```
prices={PriceDraftDsl[
    channel=Reference{
        typeId='channel', 
        id='b5c57a89-4f18-41eb-b5c3-e0de1c09cf81', 
        obj=null},
        country=<null>,
        custom=<null>,
        customerGroup=<null>,
        tiers=<null>,
        validFrom=<null>,
        validUntil=<null>,
        value=USD 12]}
```

When I tried to do ProductSync with the above prices, I got the following error exception.

```
ReferenceResolutionException: Failed to resolve 'channel'
reference on PriceDraft with country:'null' and value: 'USD 12'. 
Reason: Channel with key 'b5c57a89-4f18-41eb-b5c3-e0de1c09cf81' 
does not exist.
```

Is there any way I can get the channel's key instead of a random UUID for channelId? and if not, Can I maybe get the channel details by using this ID?

---

I am currently using version `1.7.0` for `commercetools-sync-java` package.
I'm pretty new at this. Any help on this is deeply appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: " ... does not have the Channel Key as `channelId`. "

Resource **Key** and Resource **ID** are two different things that exist for every commercetools resource. Why do you expect these values to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, The product price does not contain channel key only a channel id.
The sync java library does provide channel key resolution and so it expects that your price draft will contain the key.

https://github.com/commercetools/commercetools-sync-java/blob/master/docs/usage/PRODUCT_SYNC.md#syncing-from-an-external-resource

Does that help?

Best Regards
Brian

You might also consider using the Import API

https://docs.commercetools.com/tutorials/import-and-export#import-api